# Ros publisher not working with V-Rep after saving

Tags: simulation, ros, publisher

I've started using V-Rep to simulate some robots (Pioneers and quadrotors, initially), but I've been having problems when I try to connect it with ROS. I tried to replicate the example from RosTopicPublisherAndSubscriber.ttt and it only works the first time, after I close it and load it again, it doesn't work anymore, my code is practically identical to the example, except that I use getPose and it's a Pioneer (the one that comes with V-Rep), here's my code:

```
if (simGetScriptExecutionCount()==0) then

    -- Check if the required plugin is there (libv_repExtRos.so or libv_repExtRos.dylib):
    local moduleName=0
    local moduleVersion=0
    local index=0
    local pluginNotFound=true
    while moduleName do
        moduleName,moduleVersion=simGetModuleName(index)
        if (moduleName=='Ros') then
            pluginNotFound=false
        end
        index=index+1
    end

    if (pluginNotFound) then

        simDisplayDialog('Error','ROS plugin was not found.&&nSimulation will not run properly',sim_dlgstyle_ok,false,nil,{0.8,0,0,0,0,0},{0.5,0,0,1,1,1})
    else

        -- Retrive the handle of the vision sensor we wish to stream:
        lHandle=simGetObjectHandle('Pioneer_p3dx')

        -- Now enable topic publishing and streaming of the vision sensor's data:
        topicName=simExtROS_enablePublisher('p3dx',1,simros_strmcmd_get_object_pose,lHandle,0,'')
        if (topicName == nil) then
            simDisplayDialog('Error','Nil',sim_dlgstyle_ok,false,nil,{0.8,0,0,0,0,0},{0.5,0,0,1,1,1})
        else
            simDisplayDialog('Error','Not Nil',sim_dlgstyle_ok,false,nil,{0.8,0,0,0,0,0},{0.5,0,0,1,1,1})
        end
        -- Retrive the handle of the passive vision sensor. We will use the passive vision sensor

    end
end
```

Any idea is welcome! Thanks in advance!
PS: Also, if anyone with 1500 reputation points could create the v-rep tag, that would be great!

Comment: The V-REP [forums](http://www.forum.coppeliarobotics.com/) might be a better place to post your question for now

Comment: Yeah, I also did that, I was just trying to see where I'd get the answer first, but then I totally forgot about it. I've already solved it, so I'll just post it here and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the people at V-REP helped me solve it. So basically I should used the argument as -1 instead of 0.

So basically, a should have done this

```
topicName=simExtROS_enablePublisher('p3dx',1,simros_strmcmd_get_object_pose,lHandle,-1,'')
```

instead of

```
topicName=simExtROS_enablePublisher('p3dx',1,simros_strmcmd_get_object_pose,lHandle,0,'')
```